# How to add replace tabs with 4 spaces without disturbing formatting in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have to replace tabs with 4 spaces in my notepad++ file but this would also mean that tab indents with different space indentation in consequent lines would lose formatting. Is there any other way to do it than an extended set replace.

Comment: That's not really a programming question...

Comment: Yes but i need to get tabs out before putting into git server - replace all kills all my code alignment so i am doing it manually

Comment: You can store files with tabs in git. Suggestion: Write a program that does the job for you. If that gives you problems, at least you would have a programming problem that could become an on-topic question here. That said, your question is even unclear, because surely the answers below tell you how to do what you ask, but that doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Yes - its a good suggestion to write a program for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the lines to be changed then use the Notepad++ command: Menus => **Edit** => **Blank operations** => **Tab to space**.

Comment: It still destroys formatting by converting all tabs to spaces destroying the alignment of my code

Comment: Yes it converts tabs to spaces because that is the name of the command and also what the question wants. It is possible that the file was aligned assuming a different tab width than Notepad++ uses by default, in which case see the settings field in @Ashwin Nair's answer. Otherwise please edit your question to show the sort of text that is formatted badly after using the **Tab to space** command.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you change the tab indent size by going to

`Settings -> Preferences -> Tab Settings -> Tab Size`

all previous tab sizes will change. If you see differently sized tab spaces, chances are npp is reading them as spaces.

To replace spaces, simply enter the number of spaces you want to replace in the `Find what` textbox.

To replace tabs, click the `Extended (\n, \r....)` option and enter `\t` in the `Find What` text box.

Comment: It still destroys formatting by converting all tabs to spaces destroying the alignment of my code

Comment: The whole point of tabs is to allow for aligning. ...you simply can't use fixed width spaces for alignment of variable length data fields

Comment: Yes but is there any npp extension that takes care of adjusting appropriate spaces instead of hardcoded 4 spaces to replace tabs?